# Teamcity creating too many nuget packages

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nopcommerce

I'm trying to get Teamcity to create and publish one nuget package at the end of my build. The trouble is that even when I specify a specific .nuspec file under "Specification files" nuget, in addition to creating my specified package, will also create packages for each directory in the root directory of my checked out repo.

The root directory of my repo looks like this -

[image: root dir]

so nuget pack ends up creating two extraneous packages - "src" and "upgradeScripts" that contain all files within the respective directories.

Here's my nuget pack configuration -
[image: nuget pack config]

Here's my .nuspec -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>BlahSite</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>Blah Site</title>
    <authors>Blah LLC</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Blah Blah</description>
    <releaseNotes>First release!</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\Deployable\nop_2.50\**\*.*" target="" />
  </files>
</package>
```

It's not a deal breaker but the src directory is rather large and it takes up a  lot of unnecessary space in addition to making the publish step in teamcity take 10+ mins. Any ideas? Thanks!